Property of product of sets in metric space
Let $A$ be a closed subset of a metric space $X$. Assume $W$ is an open subset of $X\times I$, such that $(A\times I) \cup (X\times 0)\subseteq W$. Show that there exists a neighborhood $V$ of $A$ such that $A\subseteq V\subseteq X$ and $V\times I\subseteq W$.
Here $I=[0,1]\subseteq \mathbb{R}$
Attempt:
Let $p:X\times I\rightarrow X$ be the projection map. Let $V'=\operatorname{proj}(W)$. Then, $A\subseteq V'$. So $A\times I \subseteq V'\times I$. But why is $V'\times I \subseteq W$?
Remark. If $X$ is compact, then tube lemma implies result. But why if $X$ general metric and $A$ only closed?

Is $I = [0, 1] \subseteq \mathbb{R}$?

@K.Jiang yes that is right

The tube lemma does apply here: the space $I = [0, 1]$ is compact. $X$ does not need to be compact or metrizable, and $A$ does not need to be closed. Furthermore, we just need $A \times I \subseteq W$: it is not critical that $X \times \{ 0 \} \subseteq W$.
For each $a \in A$, consider the set $\{ a \} \times I$, which is contained in $A \times I$, and consequently in the open set $W$. By the tube lemma, there is a neighborhood $U_a$ of $a$ in $X$ such that $U_a \times I \subseteq W$. Now, consider $V = \bigcup_{a \in A} U_a$. $V$ is a neighborhood of $A$ because for any $a \in A$, $a \in U_a \subseteq V$. And
$$V \times I = \left[ \bigcup_{a \in A} U_a \right] \times I = \bigcup_{a \in A} (U_a \times I) \subseteq W$$
since $U_a \times I \subseteq W$ for each $a \in A$.
